# Use blank space to indent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dropdown which uses the Ancestry gem and orders the option hierarchically.

It works great using the following code in the controller

```
@lines = ancestry_options(Line.all.arrange(:order => 'name')) {|i| "#{'-' * i.depth} #{i.name}" }
```

I have been trying to change the indenting character, defined by `"#{'-'` to a double space but rails ignores a space like `"#{' '`.

Is there a way I can force it to put a blank space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces are ignored not by rails, but by HTML. You can try to convert each space to `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space), but don't forget to include `.html_safe` in the end of you string.

Comment: This is what I was looking for but I can't get it to work. Should the `&nbsp;` be inside the single quotes? Should .html_safe be at the very end? The following throws up an exception.     `@lines = ancestry_options(Line.all.arrange(:order => 'name')) {|i| "#{'&nbsp;' * i.depth} #{i.name}" }.html_safe`

Comment: It should look like this: `@lines = ancestry_options(Line.all.arrange(:order => 'name')) {|i| "#{'&nbsp;' * i.depth} #{i.name}".html_safe }`

Comment: Fantastic. Just what I wanted. Thank you.